# How to use logical operators in ant?

Tags: ant

i have a small peice of code which prints if platform is unix or windowsas

```
<if>
<equals=${arg1} value="linux-86"/>
<then>
<echo message="linux"
<then>
<elseif>
<equals=${arg1} value="linux-64"/>
<then>
<echo message="linux"/>
</then>
</elseif>
<else>
<echo message="Windows">
</else>
</if>
```

Here we can see we are unnecessarily checking first two conditions for same message,is there any OR operator in ant like we have in c ||,so that we can write arg1=linux-64||linux-86....if there is please tell me how should i use this will save up lot of time here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<condition property="WinPlatform.Check">
        <or>
            <equals arg1="${param1}" arg2="win-x86"/>
            <equals arg1="${param1}" arg2="win-x86-client"/>
            <equals arg1="${param1}" arg2="win-x64"/>
        </or>
    </condition>

<target name="Mytarget" if="WinPlatform.Check">
        <echo message="executing windows family build:::${param1}"/>
    </target>
```

now call `Mytarget` with your parameter,it will work

Answer (score 1):

The `if` task is part of [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/). It is not available in core Ant.

Various [conditions](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html) are available in core Ant and can be used, for example, to make target execution conditional.

Before 1.8, if/unless conditions evaluate "is the property set?"

```
<target name="test" if="foo" unless="bar"/>
```

From 1.8, if/unless conditions can evaluate "is the property true/false":

```
<target name="test" if="${foo}" unless="${bar}"/>
```

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you have a look in the ant manual? http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html

Or google for "ant if task".

Comment: they are giving me simple if task as i showed above,but i can't get it anywhere so i thought someone might have used it here

Comment: i got the answer but can't post it before 7 hours so wait till then